# Two-Phase-Initialization vs. logger events

Tags: c#

We have some classes where we need to fire events during initialization. The current state is that we use emtpy ctors, then attach all the events we need and then use `init()` to fully initialize the object.

Id like to get rid of this two-phase-initialization. Its ugly and causes problems when using the objects without initialization (we tried the 'isInitialized' flag, but that ugly too...).

Is there a better way to attach events to an object which are needed during initialization?

Edit:
Its code like this:

```
public class ExampleClass {
  public int value;
  public event ErrorHandling OnError;

  public ExampleClass(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  void init() {
    // do something with that value
    OnError?.Invoke(value); // something went wrong
  }
}

int main() {
  ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass(2);
  example.OnError += // some error handling
  example.init();
}
```

Its a very limited example. But in fact I cant get rid of the events during initialization.

TIA

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @stuartd I did.

Comment: I'm using the same construction, haven't found a better one. But...If the OnError is declared in a baseclass/interface (so you'll use this construction often) You could pass the OnError handler into the constructor. Or even the logger or error handler class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use events? Either pass an IErrorHandler into the constructor (ideally with dependency injection), or like pass an Action that will be run instead of the event

Comment: Unfortunately I need them as the whole codebase is designed as to use many many events

Comment: You can pass the class into the constructor, then add the event from there? Although make sure to make the object disposable and remove the event afterwards